# runtime error (SIGBART) - SPOJ Bicolorable

Tags: c++11, runtime-error

I'm doing [this](http://www.spoj.com/problems/BICOLOR/) problem on SPOJ and I keep getting a runtime error (SIGABRT) and I've never really experienced this for.  When I run my code in VS it works properly but SPOJ gives me this error.  I was wondering if you could tell me why I'm getting it.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

vector<int> marked;
vector<vector<int>> edges;
bool colorable;

void bfs(int v) {
    colorable = true;

    switch (marked[v]) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
        marked[v] = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < edges[v].size(); i++) {
            if (marked[edges[v][i]] != 1) {
                marked[edges[v][i]] = 2;
            }
            else {
                colorable = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        break;

    case 2:
        for (int i = 0; i < edges[v].size(); i++) {
            if (marked[edges[v][i]] != 2) {
                marked[edges[v][i]] = 1;
            }
            else {
                colorable = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int N, M, a, b;

    while (scanf("%d", &N) != 0) {
        colorable = true;

        while (N--) {
            marked.push_back(0);


    edges.push_back({ });
    }

    scanf("%d", &M);
    while (M--) {
        scanf("%d", &a);
        scanf("%d", &b);
        edges[a].push_back(b);
        edges[b].push_back(a);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < marked.size(); i++) {
        bfs(i);
    }

    colorable ? printf("BICOLORABLE\n") : printf("NOT BICOLORABLE\n");

    marked.clear();
    edges.clear();
}

return 0;
}
```

I've tried Googling other similar issues and what a SIGABRT error is exactly and I'm still confused. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `SIGABRT` is a special [POSIX signal](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04) that tells you that the [`abort`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/abort.html) function has been used to terminate the program, which is usually done because of unhandled exceptions or similar. You could get exceptions (that abort the program) if you try to allocate to much memory, how big is the data-set you're reading?

Comment: N is anywhere between 1 and 1024 and M is anywhere between 1 and 30000.

Comment: That means your program can use up to about 235MB (potentially much more depending on how `std::vector` allocates its memory). Not so much on a normal PC these days, but does SPOJ support it?

Comment: Oh, and on an unrelated note, why do you use `scanf` and `printf` in a C++ program?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg They are faster than cin and cout. At least that's what I'm told. SPOJ recommends using them. And I am not sure if SPOJ supports it, do you know how to check that? Or do I just need to solve this problem a different way?

Comment: Oh I found the memory limit for this problem: 1536MB.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and in case anyone ever has a similar issue I'll post it here. The line

```
while(scanf("%d", &N) != 0)
```

is apparently not appreciated by SPOJ.  I split it into two lines

```
scanf("%d", &N);
while(N !=0 ) {}
```

and everything worked just fine.  Thanks for your comments to help me understand the error.

Comment: These two code blocks do different things. The first compares the return of `scanf("%d", &N)` (i.e the numbers of elements that could be read) to zero. It is usually done to check if you have reached EOF (end-of-file). The second approach compares the value of N to zero, which is completely different. One way to both read N and check if N is different than 0 in a single line is by doing `while (scanf("%d", &N) && N != 0)`, or simply `while(scanf("%d", &N) && N)`.